# A/V calls in Conversations (xmpp)

Tags: xmpp, chat, conversation-scope

Audio and video calls are work fine When  mobile phones are in the same network,
but when mobile phones are in different network audio and video calls are not work,
we implement our **own server** using http://help.conversations.im/ this reference.
we can't find solution.

What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a secundary server to make these calls, some servers have some pluggins for example openfire has one called PionTURN as a plug. but any TURN server will do it. i recommend "coTURN" then just install discovery pluggin in your server and configure it to point it to your TURN server.